# Why I am getting Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Type' instances are not supported. Path: $.EntityMapper.ForType.?

Tags: c#, litedb

I am new to LiteDatabase. I have the following db.

```cs
using (var db = new LiteDatabase(@"MyData.db"))
{
    var users = db.GetCollection<User>("users");
    return new JsonResult(users);
}
```

When I try convert users to json.

```
var d = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(users);
```

I am getting

> Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Type' instances are not supported. Path: $.EntityMapper.ForType.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: @Progman what is the problem with the question format.

Comment: @user123456 - there was no tag for [tag:litedb] so people may not have known what `LiteDatabase` was.

Comment: @dbc I will delete it

Comment: @user123456 - In my opinion there is no reason to delete it given that @GuruStron was able to understand it and answer it, and the answer might be useful to other [tag:litedb] users.  Maybe just [edit] it to add a sentence explaining what `LiteDatabase` since the tag isn't well known?  Or actually, why did you remove the [tag:litedb] tag when having it substantially clarifies the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FindAll()`

```cs
return new JsonResult(users.FindAll());
```

`GetCollection<T>` returns `ILiteCollection<T>` which is implemented by [`LiteCollection<T>`](https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/blob/5ec64e5bd2453e506bd135ace1b1c0ab5717d3f5/LiteDB/Client/Database/LiteCollection.cs) which has members storing type info (like [`EntityMapper`](https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/blob/5ec64e5bd2453e506bd135ace1b1c0ab5717d3f5/LiteDB/Client/Mapper/EntityMapper.cs#L19) with `Type ForType` property).